# How to get list of values of a single key from JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, variables, select, fetch

I have these list, and I want to get the value of name:

```
[{
  "tr": [{
      "name": "#For5Rs",
      "promoted_content": null,
      "query": "%23For5Rs",
      "events": null
  }, {
      "name": "Javed Bashir",
      "promoted_content": null,
      "query": "%22Javed+Bashir%22",
      "events": null
  }, {
      "name": "Milan Luthria",
      "promoted_content": null,
      "query": "%22Milan+Luthria%22",
      "events": null
  }, {
      "name": "Vidya Balan",
      "promoted_content": null,
      "query": "%22Vidya+Balan%22",
      "events": null
  }],
  "as_of": "2013-08-16T10:31:35Z",
  "created_at": "2013-08-16T10:20:41Z",
  "locations": [{
      "name": "India",
      "woeid": 23424848
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add what have you tried so far and the error that you got. Also we need more info about your question, is that just a list or json data?

Comment: can you give a code to get all value of name in tr list

Comment: Okay, `data = __import__('json').loads(your_json_data)[0]; [print(i) for i in data['tr']]`.

Comment: have you got solution yet!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for element in data['tr']:
    print element['name']
    print element['promoted_content']
    print element['query']
    print element['events']
```

Answer (score 6):

You are asking, "I have a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary has a key `"name"`. How do I get a list of values of all those keys?"

### Basics

- Access list elements using an index in brackets. `a[0]` is the first element of a list.
- Access dictionary values using the key in brackets. `a["name"]` is `this_value` from `{"name":this_value}`.
- Aggregate values with a loop like so:

  ```
  aggregator = []
  for item in a_list:
      aggregator.append(value_calculated_from(item))
  ```

### Problems with question

`your_list` doesn't have the square brackets paired up.

I'll suppose

```
outer_dictionary = your_list[0]
list_of_dictionaries = outer_dictionary['tr']
```

### Answer

You can get the list of values of "name":

```
names = []
for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries:
    if "name" in dictionary:
        names.append(dictionary["name"])
```

Comment: Did you tell OP about how to covert json data to Python object?

Comment: @Kevin-Guan, I read his comment to mean he had done that already with loads(). Afzal, are you asking how to get this data into a Python variable or how to extract the "name" values once the JSON is in a variable?

Comment: Yes, I think he knows about that. But if you're going to post a full answer, the full solution about the problem is needed.

Comment: And I think you're doing right, OP wants extract some values by keys from the dict that in the list.

Answer (score 2):

I see your data was not formatted completely(before editing)- so i would go for regex-Below code extracts all name from the supplied json **STRING**(just enclose """""")

```
import re
data="""[{
  "tr": [{
      "name": "#For5Rs",
      "promoted_content": null,
      "query": "%23For5Rs",
      "events": null
  }, {
      "name": "Javed Bashir",
      "promoted_content": null,
      "query": "%22Javed+Bashir%22",
      "events": null
  }, {
      "name": "Milan Luthria",
      "promoted_content": null,
      "query": "%22Milan+Luthria%22",
      "events": null
  }, {
      "name": "Vidya Balan",
      "promoted_content": null,
      "query": "%22Vidya+Balan%22",
      "events": null
  }],
  "as_of": "2013-08-16T10:31:35Z",
  "created_at": "2013-08-16T10:20:41Z",
  "locations": [{
      "name": "India",
      "woeid": 23424848
  }]
"""

names=re.findall(r'(?<="name":\s").+(?=",[\s\S]+"promoted_content")',data)
print names
```

It prints a list-

```
['#For5Rs', 'Javed Bashir', 'Milan Luthria', 'Vidya Balan']
```

Comment: Did you really understand what's the OP wants? Please see the comments.

Comment: Ah! OK all inside `tr`.

Comment: I think that OP isn't trying to do this...I'll ask OP about what's his really wants.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the list of names

```
new_list = [x['name'] for x in data['tr']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
for element in data[key]:
   #print your values here
```